# pull private repo from GitHub to my local location

Tags: git, github

when I pull a public repo like this:

```
git init
git remote add origin git@github.com:user_name/repo_name.git
git pull origin master
```

It works:

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 36, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (36/36), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (25/25), done.
remote: Total 36 (delta 10), reused 36 (delta 10), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (36/36), done.
From github.com:user_name/repo_name
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
```

But when I change access to Private and do repeate,
it show me error:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I do to get correct access rights?

tips:

1. I am the author of the repo
2. I have add ssh key to "Settings"

Comment: Please check your user_name and repo_name in GitHub URL. Could be some typo, which is causing this error.

Comment: My guess is that your default SSH key (provided by `~/.ssh/id_rsa` or `ssh-agent`) is valid for a different GitHub user, and isn't the same as the key you've added to settings.

Try running `ssh git@github.com` and see what username it responds back with (something like `Hi qixiangZ! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`)

Comment: @msbit
hi, msbit, you're right!
In my window computer, whether it is private or public, repo can be pulled 
correctly。but in my mac computer, it can't work。I do this action: ssh git@github.com ，it show me : Hi user_name/repo_name! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access。

Comment: @msbit mac computer and window computer use diffenent id_rsa,but two id_rsa.sh has added to my github settings!

Comment: Interesting. What I'd suggest, given that, is to run: `ssh -v git@github.com` and look for the lines containing `Offering public key` and `Server accepts key`. These will let you know what key files are being considered, and which one is ultimately accepted by the server. If the line has `agent` at the end of it, then you could tell `ssh-agent` to not use it (via `ssh-add -d` or `ssh-add -D`, information [here](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-add.1)). Then you'll need to work out where that is set in your login scripts (`.profile` etc).